# TypeScript with Angular: CORS protocol

Tags: angular, typescript, cors

I'm sending this request to my REST endpoint:

```
this.http.request(path, requestOptions);
```

where `path` is: `http://localhost:8082/commty/cmng/users`
and `requestOptions`:

```
{
    headers: { user: "sdf", password: "sdf" }
}
```

The problem is BROWSER tries to get CORS permission before sending my request.

This is the CORS HTTP BROWSER `curl` request:

```
 curl "http://localhost:8082/commty/cmng/users" -X OPTIONS
   -H "Host: localhost:8082"
   -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
   -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT"
   -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: passwd,user"
   -H "Origin: http://localhost:3000"
   -H "Connection: keep-alive"
```

After having sent this CORS request, a `200-OK` response status in received BUT the flow is interrupted, so my request is not sent.

The content of the response is:

```
Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }
```

This is my `CORSFilter.java`:

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter
{

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException
    {   
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }

}
```

However I'm getting this response from my sever:

```
Object {
  _body: error,
  status: 0,
  ok: false,
  statusText: "",
  headers: Object,
  type: 3,
  url: null
}
```

[image]

**Error Message**

```
Object {
  _body: error,
  status: 0,
  ok: false,
  statusText: "",
  headers: Object,
  type: 3,
  url: null
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @CrossOrgin annotation instead of using this filter, in this filter some time due to configuration failure it will throw some exception but if you are using @CrossOrgin you can resolve this problem